# Using system function in the bash, causes problem with output

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, firewall, ufw

So, i want to filter some values using awk, to insert them to the file after this so that they don't appear in the script file, for this im trying to use system grep function

and im getting this output everytime i use the script

```
/sbin/ufw deny from 187.210.68.101
to any
/sbin/ufw deny from 45.88.221.190
to any
/sbin/ufw deny from 5.253.235.40
to any
```

but i need

```
/sbin/ufw deny from 187.210.68.101 to any
/sbin/ufw deny from 45.88.221.190 to any
/sbin/ufw deny from 5.253.235.40 to any
```

also, my 4 string is getting removed

lines brokes everytime

```
awk '{ if (system("grep -L "$1" banned.txt")) print "/sbin/ufw deny from "$1 to any" "; }' /usr/local/test/susp.txt >> /usr/local/test/script.sh
```

Im trying to fix it of course, so that the ufw deny rule is displayed on the same line with all arguments without any bugs, and does not output anywhere there banned.txt because it shouldn't be written there

Comment: Please provide a sample of your actual input file, not just an image of the output

Comment: remove the image and instead cut-n-paste 5-10 lines into the question; please provide samples from all input files

Comment: also, update the question to show the expected output (corresponding to the sample inputs)

Comment: @Cyrus how you html help me with the bash?

Comment: @Conspiracy: you can use markdown or/and HTML syntax to format your question.

Comment: Regarding `Using system function in the bash` - the system function is in your awk script, not bash. Your question really has very little, if anything, to do with bash. Having said that, a shell such as bash is a tool designed to sequence calls to other tools while awk is a tool designed to manipulate text - you're trying to use awk as if it were a shell which is generally a bad idea.

Comment: So far you've shown us output you get and output you want but you haven't shown is the input you're parsing to get that output - [edit] your question to add that input so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -L` prints the names of the files that matched the regular expression, so it prints `banned.txt` whenever it finds a match. That output is being included in the `awk` output, so it gets written to the output file.

If you just want to know if `grep` found a match, use `grep -q`. This suppresses the output, so you can just test the exit status.

Using `grep` for this seems like overkill. It looks like you just want to find all the lines that are in common between the two files. You can do this with the `comm` command.

```
comm -12 <(sort banned.txt) <(sort /usr/local/test/susp.txt) | awk '{print "/sbin/ufw deny from ", $0, "to any"}' >> /usr/local/test/script.sh
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, but i still have problem with your code, to any on other line

https://i.imgur.com/Qz2r7yc.png

Comment: Make sure your files have Unix newlines, not DOS CRLF. Use `dos2unix` to fix the files.

Comment: I was missing a space before `"to any"`, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Okay, it works now, but i don't know, everytime i use this, my line in end of file removes, i should have 4 strings in results, but i have 3

Comment: @Conspiracy: please stop posting images of text. Thank you.

Comment: Unix text tools generally require that all files end with a newline. If the last line is missing a newline, the last line may be missed. @Conspiracy